# When/How to delete Semaphores in C

Tags: c, semaphore

I am writing a simple programm, which is using shared memory and semaphores to lock it while reading or writing. After the programm finishes all shared memory and semaphores have to be deleted. we got our own sem library that implements the functions seminit,semrm, semgrab, semdown, semup.I've got the programm working, but I am unclear on the semaphore deleting part.

Since all Semaphores have to be deleted at the end, while the programm is called multiple times, when do I delete them? I mean, I have to make sure i dont delete them while they are still in use. is there any possibility to check whether it is still in use?

I am not sure how to tackle this issue.

short problem summary:
programm is called multiple times, semaphore needs to be deleted at the end, only one programm has to handle it, not another that is cleaning up.

Comment: If you have your own library, why you ask here ? Ask the implementator and see the documentation, if any.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the goal, but wouldn't it be possible (if silly) to have a semaphore manage the status of your semaphores?

Comment: I have thought of that,but how do I delete that one then?

Comment: Hmmm.. my question was not clear enough. I was not asking about my library, but how it is done in general. How to delete it, when used in a single programm that is called multiple times.

Comment: I guess this boils down to knowing when your program execution is completely finished? (And to avoid having to solve the halting problem along the way!)

Comment: How are you freeing the shared memory? Free the semaphore when you free the shared memory, since there's no longer anything for the semaphore to lock.

Answer (score -1):

Without more details on libraries and how you are using the semaphore, I would go with a combination of the Singleton pattern and reference counting.

A description of the Singleton pattern can be found on Wikipedia: [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

I would make the semaphore a Singleton, and add a variable to track the number of instances of the semaphore that have been given out.  I would increment the variable in the `getInstance()` method.  I would then add a `releaseInstance()` method to the semaphore class that decrements the counter.  `releaseInstance()` would be called when the program is done using the semaphore.  Then, I would add an `isInUse()` method to check if the reference count is 0.  If it is, you can delete the semaphore.

So, your program would have something like:

```
mySemaphore.releaseInstance();
if(mySemaphore.isInUse() != true) {
    delete mySemaphore;
}
else {
    // Do nothing since it is a Singleton, and someone else is using it.
    // i.e. - We don't need to delete anything.
}
```

Comment: In other words you would use some kind of shared memory that increments every time a process is trying to get a lock and decrements when it is finished with it. but then again what if one is just finished decrements while others are initiated, but havent incremented the variable yet, and the former process deletes it since it hasnt been incremented?

Comment: "Singletons, delete, ..." It seems that this answer is about some object oriented language (i.e. C++) when the question is clearly about C. Furthermore, this answer describes something like a smart pointer, why not simply using a std::shared_ptr (in C++ of course)?